# How to rename a consistently-named subdirectory across multiple directories?

Tags: linux, bash, rename, fish, batch-rename

I'm wanting to rename

```
123/1/ -> 123/v1/
foo/1/ -> foo/v1/
bar/1/ -> bar/v1/
345/1/ -> 345/v1/
```

I've searched and found a few related solutions, but not quite sure what is best in this instance. e.g.,

```
find . -wholename "*/1" -exec echo '{}' \;
```

successfully prints out all the paths relative to `.`, but `{}` expands to `./foo/1/`, so I can't move from `{}` to `{}/v1` for instance. I also tried

```
find . -wholename "*/1" -exec mv '{}' $(echo '{}' | sed 's/1/v1/') \;
```

with the idea that I would be invoking `mv ./foo/1 ./foo/v1`, but apparently it tries to move `.foo/1/` to a subdirectory of itself.

Anyhow, just looking for the simplest way to do this bulk renaming. To be clear, I'm trying to move the literal subdirectory `1` to `v1`, not also `2` to `v2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this, using [perl rename](https://man.archlinux.org/man/rename.1p.en) (which may be different than the `rename` already existing on your system, use `rename --version` to check):

```
rename -n 's|([^/]+/)(1)|$1v$2|' */1/
```

remove `-n` (dry-run) when the outputs is ok for you.

(note that you can use `globstar` on bash or something similar on other shells to recurse into deeper sub-directories)

Comment: Can this be used to add an additional level of a subdirectory as well, such as `foo/1/` -> `foo/tmp/v1`? Or does it only operate on renaming the leaf nodes it finds?

Comment: Also, this just fails with exit code 4. What is the $2 doing there exactly? What groups are being extracted?

Comment: Post edited to work _recursively_. The capture groups are there to put `v` between the first capture group and the second one. Can you retry since my new edit for error ?

Comment: No, it still errors out with code 4 ('nothing was renamed' from the man page). But I see how the capture groupings are supposed to be working now.

Comment: What is the output of `rename --version` and your OS ?

Comment: @Nathan I don't get an error out of it, but I also don't see any of your examples renamed either.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a silly mistake. I already had `rename` on my system, and didn't realize `perl rename` was a separate entity. I've installed `perl-rename` specifically, and I get how to use it now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: perl's rename is quite more popular than the one you used

Comment: This tool is awesome! After doing the initial renaming I needed, I wanted to move everything under a nested subdirectory, and it worked perfectly with `perl-rename 's|([^/]+/)(v1)|$1main/$2|' */v1` (it injected a `main` subdirectory under the top level).

Comment: Sure, it's a must have tool

Comment: Would you mind if I edited your answer to remove or de-emphasize globstar usage, before I accept it? I'm not using bash personally for my main shell, and would prefer the accepted answer be shell agnostic.

Comment: Up to you ;) Precise your shell/OS where it works. fish+bash (?)

Comment: Alrightly, made shell agnostic and a few small edits, and accepted! Thanks again, I've aliased `perl-rename` to simply `rename`, and I have a feeling this tool is going to be a lifesaver.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, untested, is IMHO the simplest way to do it using bash builtins and mandatory POSIX utils as long as your paths don't contain newlines:

```
while IFS= read -r old; do
    new="${old##*/}v1"
    echo mv -- "$old" $new"
done < <(find . -type d -name 1)
```

Remove `echo` once you're happy with the output from initial testing.

Answer (score 2):

This was tagged with fish. A solution using fish shell:

```
for file in **/1/; mv $file (dirname $file)/v1; end
```

Comment: that's actually quite clean. While you're here, mind if I ask how this could be expanded a bit? What if I wanted to add in a layer of a subdirectory with fish, so move `*/v1* -> */tmp/v1` across multiple directories? (if you'd rather I open a different question for that, let me know)

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to do what I wanted with the perl rename utility. Still, I appreciate this answer, it's nice seeing some cool fish scripting!

Comment: Something like this, assuming you need to create intermediate directories: `for file in **/1/; mkdir -p (dirname $file)/tmp/; mv $file (dirname $file)/tmp/v1; end`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
find . -depth -type d -name 1 -execdir mv 1 v1 \;
```

- The `-execdir` option to `find` is not POSIX, but it is widely supported by `find` implementations.
- See [What are the security issues and race conditions in using `find -exec`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/273965/264812) for useful information about the `-execdir` option.
- The `-depth` option is necessary both to support paths like `foo/1/1/1` and to avoid warning messages when `find` can't traverse the newly-renamed `1` directories.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in straight Bash.

Given:

```
$ tree .
.
├── 123
│   └── 1
├── 345
│   └── 1
│       └── 1        # this is a file named '1'
├── bar
│   └── 1
└── foo
    └── 1
        └── file
8 directories, 2 files
```

You can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
new_1="v1"

for src in **/*/1; do      # will RECURSIVELY find any directory '1'
                           # if just next level (as in example)
                           # you can just do */1
    [ -d "$src" ] || continue 
    tgt="${src%%/1}/$new_1"
    echo "./$src/ => ./$tgt/"
    mv  "./$src" "./$tgt/"
done
```

Result:

```
$ tree .
.
├── 123
│   └── v1
├── 345
│   └── v1
│       └── 1
├── bar
│   └── v1
└── foo
    └── v1
        └── file
 8 directories, 2 files
```

If you want to insert parent directories, add one statement to create them:

```
shopt -s globstar
new_1="a parent/v1"         # the replacement path has a parent

for src in **/*/1; do 
    [ -d "$src" ] || continue 
    tgt="${src%%/1}/$new_1"
    [[ "/" == *"$new_1"* ]] || mkdir -p "${tgt%/*}"  # create parents if any
    echo "./$src/ => ./$tgt/"
    mv  "./$src" "./$tgt/"
done
```

Result:

```
$ tree .
.
├── 123
│   └── a parent
│       └── v1
├── 345
│   └── a parent
│       └── v1
│           └── 1
├── bar
│   └── a parent
│       └── v1
└── foo
    └── a parent
        └── v1
            └── file
 12 directories, 2 files
```

Comment: That looks like a comprehensive solution! I ended up using `perl-rename` which worked great, but I'll keep this in my back pocket. I've never seen the `tree` command before, that's really useful.